# Pandas TA-Lib Save current indicator computations

Tags: python

I have Ohlcv values stored in my database that ranges from a thousand timestamps. Initially I would do a technical analysis on Ta-Lib that would compute for technical indicators from those thousands of timestamps.

in order to save time, is it possible to store my current computed indicators for future reference? For example, I would do a MACD on a timestamp of 1000, how can I use that computed value when I would compute MACD again when I would have another 1000 thousand timestamp without recomputing the previous 1000?